# Does every compact abelian group contain a Kronecker set generating a dense subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact metrizable abelian group with infinite exponent.

Let $S^1 = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \right\}$. A set $K \subset G$ is a *Kronecker set* if, for every continuous function $f : K \to S^1$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a character $\chi \in \hat{G}$ such that $|f(x) - \chi(x)| < \varepsilon$ for every $x \in K$.

A set is *perfect* if it is closed with no isolated points.

It is known that $G$ contains a perfect Kronecker set (a construction is given, for example, in Section 5.2 of Rudin's *Fourier Analysis on Groups*). For an application of Kronecker sets, I want to be able to control the subgroup generated by $K$. Namely, I want to know if the following is true:

**Problem:** Does there exist a perfect Kronecker set $K \subset G$ such that the subgroup generated by $K$ is dense in $G$?

I thought of trying to make an argument using Zorn's lemma, but this appears to be a dead end: a nested union of Kronecker sets need not be Kronecker.

I was able to find some interesting results about subgroups generated by Kronecker sets (e.g., in [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2388789) of Biró and [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2729343) one by Gabriyelyan). However, I was not able to find anything directly addressing density in the existing literature.